# Log file modifications in Windows

Tags: windows, file, logging

I'm trying to find a way to log the modification of a simple textfile into a log in Windows.
I just can't seem to solve it using the auditing tool for Event viewer since it only records authorization, not modification. OR I'm doing it wrong.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly is being asked here. Are you trying to log events that are generated whenever a particular file is being modified?

Perhaps you want to investigate using [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Well yeah, I'm trying to figure out when someone makes a change to a file and log it.